# unable to build codename one app after adding admobfullscreen lib

Tags: admob, codenameone

I have just completed my app,all good and fine till i added the admob fullscreen lib file and followed the instructions there. it works on the simulator(just shows the codename one icon as the ad content). on building the app, i get an error from the build servers. something like this:

Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/tmp/build2300287277349891895xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/codename1/admob/AdMobNativeImpl.java:3: error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
^
/tmp/build2300287277349891895xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/codename1/admob/AdMobNativeImpl.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
            ^
  symbol:   class InterstitialAd
  location: class AdMobNativeImpl
/tmp/build2300287277349891895xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/codename1/admob/AdMobNativeImpl.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(activity);
                           ^
  symbol:   class InterstitialAd
  location: class AdMobNativeImpl
/tmp/build2300287277349891895xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/codename1/admob/AdMobNativeImpl.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                                       ^
  symbol:   class AdListener
  location: class AdMobNativeImpl
/tmp/build2300287277349891895xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/codename1/admob/AdMobNativeImpl.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
            final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                  ^
  symbol:   class AdRequest
  location: class AdMobNativeImpl
/tmp/build2300287277349891895xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/codename1/admob/AdMobNativeImpl.java:106: error: package AdRequest does not exist
            final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                                                     ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
6 errors
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 7.981 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --debug option to get more log output.
  Above is the error output

Please i need help. Dont know what to do. Thanks all

Comment: The Android gradle logs are VERY badly done and rather confusing. This isn't the error as the error was mentioned above that. We'll need the full log to help. Edit your post with the full log then comment here so I get a notification

Comment: Thanks, I ve just edited it, is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you added the build hints listed in the [extension page](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/admobfullscreen-codenameone)

Notice that the plugin is old so it doesn't include that by default, I think you should ignore the includeGplayServices hint.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though another problem just popped up.After building successfully it crashes on any android phone i place it on(unfortunately *appname* has stooped) . But when I remove the admobfullscreen lib, it doesn't crash

Comment: Can you connect a cable to the device and get the exception error from the DDMS log?

Comment: Connect the device with a USB cable to your machine. Download the native Android SDK and launch the Android SDK's DDMS utility that prints out the device logs.