# Codename One Full Screen Google Ad not loading

Tags: codenameone, fullscreen, admob

I have an Android app that I want to use with full screen Google ads.

I have got the small ad running, but the full screen ad does show any content.

The information I found on the internet is a little conflicting.

This link here https://github.com/chen-fishbein/admobfullscreen-codenameone advises to add several build hints to the project, but then it refuses to build.

The other one here https://github.com/shannah/admobfullscreen-codenameone does not mention any build hints, but then the ads won't load.

The answer here [unable to build codename one app after adding admobfullscreen lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924124/unable-to-build-codename-one-app-after-adding-admobfullscreen-lib) tells to ignore the includeGplayServices hint.

I have build the project with the sample code, but to no avail.

What would be the correct approach?

Edit : code added

```
    String idTest = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
    String idReal = "ca-app-pub-3524209908223138~0000000000";

    admobTestId = new AdMobManager(idTest);
    admobRealId = new AdMobManager(idReal);

    f.addComponent(new Button(new Command("admob test load and show"){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

           admobTestId.loadAndShow();

        }

    }));

    f.addComponent(new Button(new Command(" admob real load & show"){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            admobRealId.loadAndShow();
        }

    }));
```

Comment: The latter one is the one from shannah. Try removing all of the build hints you didn't add then use refresh libs. That version of the lib adds the necessary build hint. Make sure your ad key is correct and active

Comment: Shai, is the ad supposed to be in the format ca-app-pub ..... ? Mine starts with pub, do I need to add the prefix ca-app- ? Does the full screen ad also work with the test key as explained here : https://www.codenameone.com/blog/adding-google-play-ads.html? And, are the ads supposed to work in the simulator, or only on the installed device?

Comment: I haven't used these so I don't really know, I suggest testing on the device and looking through the device console to see if warnings are printed out.

Comment: I have created a test app with the instructions outlined here https://github.com/shannah/admobfullscreen-codenameone , cleaned the build hints an updated the libraries ..... still I can't see any ads. Only the banner ad works. There are no error messages..

Comment: Do you show the ad? You need to explicitly show them with this API

Comment: I copied and pasted the entire coffee sample from here https://github.com/shannah/admobfullscreen-codenameone . Added the library and refreshed it.

Comment: * copied and pasted the entire code sample

Comment: You don't see anything printed to the log when you press the buttons? Which branch in the if statements is hit?

Comment: In an effort to narrow this down, I have installed and tested the StartScreenAd API and it works perfectly both in the simulator and on the installed device. So does the banner ad. The Admob ad works in the simulator. I can see an extra dialog opening with an X in the top corner to close it. On the installed device, though, not extra dialog opens and I can see no ad. There are no error messages. I have added some code for you to see my recent approach.

Comment: Shouldn't there be separate ID's for iPhone/Android/Web? I don't think you can mix them.

Comment: They are both Android Ids ... one is the for the Android test ad and the other one for the real Android ad. I am not using any iOS reference at this moment.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, can you file an issue we'll try to verify if there was a regression.